# Attach to running MAUI App on Android Phone

Tags: android, .net, debugging, mobile, maui

So I am using Visual Studio 2022, developing a .Net MAUI App. Sometimes my App will go into background or stop and the debugger will detach.

How can I reattach to debugging the App when it continues running?

Sorry, I'm new to developing for mobile apps with MAUI. I know that App is supposed to stop but that doesn't make debugging easier...

Thank you!

Comment: Android "stops" apps only if it is running out of RAM. What phone do you use and how much RAM has it? Xamarin/MAUI apps tend to require a bit more RAM than common apps to my experience. So make sure to use a phone with a lot of RAM.

Comment: Hum, I just from VS hit the run again, and it re-attaches that way - however, that in effect is a restart on the phone. And even when you stop debugging, I will still often on the phone hit the [] button, and then swipe though active apps, adnd then swipe up the app on the phone to be 100% be sure I have un-loaded the application on the phone side.

Comment: @Robert I don't think it's the amount of memory. The App uses OIDC with WebAuthenticator and it happens very deterministically when the authenticator opens the website to login in. I just have to wait a certain amount of time and the App will stop.

Comment: 1. You can refer to [Attach to running processes with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/attach-to-running-processes-with-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022), select Debug > Attach to Process or press Ctrl+Alt+p in Visual Studio, and use the Attach to Process dialog to attach the debugger to the process.

Comment: 2.It's suggested to report Visual Studio tooling issues is via Visual Studio's "Report a Problem" menu and then follow them on the developer community site. Please see [How to report a problem with Visual Studio - Visual Studio | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022&viewFallbackFrom=vs-201).

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow up on this one. Also I feel like "Attach to Process" will only attach to a process on my computer which would probably be adb. I can do that but adb seems disconnected as well. But I'll investigate further once I get back to that problem.