# How do I attach debugger to an Android app made by MAUI from Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, maui

It's similar to [Attach to running MAUI App on Android Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78067955/attach-to-running-maui-app-on-android-phone) but unfortunately there's no good answer there.

I have an Android app made with MAUI Hybrid/Blazor and it has Notification and I need to debug the behavior when the app **starts** by user interaction with it (note I need to debug the behavior where the app is closed and then started, not just resumed, so when I close the app, the debugger would be detached).

I have followed the instruction at [Android: how to debug app's start-up process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16929391/android-how-to-debug-apps-start-up-process) but the final step involves attach the debugger from *Android Studio* which I am not using, but Visual Studio so it's stuck at Waiting for Debugger if I use this method. I cannot find any way to attach a debugger to it from VS, including this old answer [How do I get Visual Studio to debug an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790089/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-to-debug-an-android-app), apparently the UI may have changed and I am also not making a "native" C++ app.

How do I debug the startup process of an Android app in Visual Studio?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why does the normal "start the app with the debugger" not work for your scenario? That allows debugging the startup behavior.

Comment: @PMF because the app is started by user interaction (here, tapping on a notification). In that case, usually the `Intent` contains a few extra info.